# Coq difficulties in defining constructors using coerced types

Tags: coq, coercion, formal-verification

### Definitions

I'm working on formalizing a typed lambda calculus in Coq, and to keep the notation manageable I've come to rely a lot on coercions. However, I've been running into some difficulties which seem odd.

Right now I'm trying to work with the following types:

- type: A descriptor of an allowable type in the language (like function, Unit, etc...)
- var: A variable type, defined as nat
- VarSets: set of vars
- Judgement: a var/my_type pair
- ty_ctx: Lists of judgements.
- ctx_join: Pairs of ty_ctx's describing disjoint sets of variables

The actual definitions are all given below, except for ctx_join which is given in the next block

```
(* Imports *)
Require Import lang_spec.
From Coq Require Import MSets.
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Module VarSet := Make(Nat_as_OT).

Inductive Judgement : Type :=
| judge (v : var) (t : type)
.

Definition ty_ctx := (list Judgement).

Definition disj_vars (s1 s2 : VarSet.t) := VarSet.Empty (VarSet.inter s1 s2).
```

Often I'd like to make statements like "this var does not appear in the set of vars bound by ty_ctx", and to that end I've set up a bunch of coercions between these types below.

```
(* Functions to convert between the different types listed above *)

Fixpoint var_to_varset (v : var) : VarSet.t :=
  VarSet.singleton v.
Coercion var_to_varset : var >-> VarSet.t.

Fixpoint bound_variables (g : ty_ctx) : VarSet.t :=
  match g with
  | nil => VarSet.empty
  | cons (judge v _) g' =>VarSet.union (VarSet.singleton v) (bound_variables g')
  end.
Coercion bound_variables : ty_ctx >-> VarSet.t.

Inductive ctx_join :=
| join_single (g : ty_ctx)
| join_double (g1 g2 : ty_ctx)
              (disjoint_proof : disj_vars g1 g2)
.

Fixpoint coerce_ctx_join (dj : ctx_join) : ty_ctx :=
  match dj with
  | join_single g => g
  | join_double g1 g2 _ => g1 ++ g2
  end.
Coercion coerce_ctx_join : ctx_join >-> ty_ctx.

Fixpoint coerce_judgement_to_ty_ctx (j : Judgement) : ty_ctx :=
  cons j nil.
Coercion coerce_judgement_to_ty_ctx : Judgement >-> ty_ctx.
```

You'll notice that the definition of `ctx_join` relies on coercing its arguments from `ty_ctx` to `VarSet`.

I've drawn up the conversion hierarchy just to make things clear
[image]

### **The Problem**

I'd like to define an inductive type with the following constructor

```
Inductive expr_has_type : ty_ctx -> nat -> type -> Prop :=
(* General Expressions *)
| ty_var (g : ty_ctx) (x : var) (t : type) (xfree : disj_vars x g)
  : expr_has_type (join_double (judge x t) g xfree) x t
.
```

The problem is that when I do, I get the following error:

```
Error:
In environment
expr_has_type : ty_ctx -> nat -> type -> Prop
g : ty_ctx
x : var
t : type
xfree : disj_vars x g
The term "xfree" has type "disj_vars x g" while it is expected to have type
 "disj_vars (judge x t) g" (cannot unify "VarSet.In a (VarSet.inter (judge x t) g)" and
"VarSet.In a (VarSet.inter x g)").
```

However, if I change the type of `xfree` to `disj_vars (VarSet.singleton x) g`, then the definition works fine! This seems very odd, as `disj_vars` is defined only on `VarSet`s, and so it seems like `x` should automatically be converted to`VarSet.singleton x` since that's how the coercion is set up.

Even weirder is the fact that if I don't set up the coercion from vars to varsets, then Coq correctly complains about applying `dis_vars` to a `var` instead of a `VarSet`. So the coercion is definitely doing *something*

Can someone explain to me why the first definition fails? Given the coercions I've set up, to me it like all the definitions above should be equivalent

**Note**

Changing the type of `xfree` to `disj_vars (judge x t) g` also fixes the error. This seems odd too, since to be able to apply `disj_vars` to `j := (judge x t)`, it first needs to be coerced to a `ty_ctx` via `cons j nil`, then to a `VarSet` via `bound_variables`, which should produce a `VarSet` containing only `x` (which is equivalent to `VarSet.singleton x`?). So this coercion chain seems to go off without a hitch, while the other one fails even though it's simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Set Printing Coercions.`, the error message will be much more informative about the problem:

```
The term "xfree" has type "disj_vars (var_to_varset x) (bound_variables g)"
while it is expected to have type
 "disj_vars (bound_variables (coerce_judgement_to_ty_ctx (judge x t)))
    (bound_variables g)"
```

The problem is that the coercion of `x` into a `VarSet.t` is equal to `Var.singleton x`, while the coercion in `judge` reduces to `VarSet.union (VarSet.singleton x) VarSet.empty`.  While these two are propositionally equal, they are not judgmentally equal, so as far as Coq is concerned, the term it came up with is ill-typed.